# cocos2d spritesheet coordinates change for different devices

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, retina-display

I'm making a game that loads images from a spritesheet. When run on an iPhone 4 simulator or an iPad simulator, the textures load correctly from the various spritesheets. When run on an iPhone 4S or 5 or retina iPads, the scale of the spritesheet changes. Pictures will help explain this better:

The spritesheet:

[image: texture map]

Correct display:

[image: correctly displaying sprites]

Wrong scale on texture map:

[image]

It's clear in the last image that the texture map is scaled 2x from first case. The coordinates used for both versions for the post in the middle are CGRectMake(5, 100, 25, 120). Am I supposed to use two texture maps for retina and normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retina was scaling the image up since it didn't have the suffix "-hd".